# Is it safe to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR with trim()

Tags: php, cross-platform

Is it safe to have something like this:

```
rtrim($pathToSomeDirectory, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

My concerns are if that backslash directory separator of Windows systems will be treated as a screening character?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you are referring to the **backslash being interpreted as an escape character**, let us look at the following code:

```
var_dump(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)
var_dump('\\')
```

The code above, will produce the result below on Windows OS:

```
string(1) "\"
string(1) "\"
```

This helps the argument for safely using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR on Windows OS, where a literal backslash is needed, e.g. an argument to trim (or its variant rtrim).

I have tested this on an almost-six-year-old version of PHP i.e. PHP 5.2.10, and DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is treated as if it were "\" (not "\", which is an un-terminated string).

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the manual for the function "rtrim" (see below) lists these characters that are to be trimmed:

> Without the second parameter, rtrim() will strip these characters:
>
> - " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> - "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> - "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> - "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> - "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NULL-byte.
> - "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: Sorry, but how does it answer my question?

Comment: Ah, I deserve backlash for that. I really didn't answer it. First, what do you mean "safe" exactly? It should trim from the right all of those and the separator (which will depend on the system) until it hits something that's not those and stop. I would test it out on a dev or inactive machine first just to make sure it gives you what you want. I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for.

Comment: My question is if `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` will be treated as screening backslash on Windows systems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's treated as a character as you have it here on both Windows and GNU/Linux systems. See http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php which shows that it's replaced with the string of that character, so similar to if you typed "\\" (on Windows) in the code where that was. Does that answer the question?

Comment: So you mean that the example in my question will strip the trailing slash on Windows system?

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly Yes, as long as the slash is the same as the separator of the system, it will strip it and the characters listed above.